# sum revenue based on criteria form another table Powerpivot

Tags: powerpivot, dax

I have a model where I have Revenue table that has revenue2016 column

another table Programs where i have 
program | min

I would like to add a calculated column to programs table so that it sums revenue that is grater than the min like so

```
=CALCULATE(SUM(Revenue[revenue2016 ]),Revenue[revenue2016]>=Programs[min])
```

this gave me an error

---

The data should look like this

```
#Revenue

Revenue
10
10
10
10
10
100
100
100
100
100
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000

#Programs

program |   min  |  summed rev  
a       |   10   |     5550 
b       |   100  |     5500 
c       |   1000 |     5000
```

Answer (score 0):

Just After I posted it I found the answer, I'll share it if someone else came across same issue

```
=calculate(sum(Revenue[revenue2016]),filter(Revenue,Revenue[revenue2016]>=Programs[Min]))
```

Comment: I tried doing this but get the following error:
"A single value for column Min in the Programs table can not be determined. This can happen when a measurement formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, number or sum for a result."